# Query to check date range between start and end dates if already exists in database in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have to allot ticket booking between two date range, ie., from an available start date and end end(which is not allotted previously). 
For this, I need to check in database if there is already any allotment happened in between these dates

For example, I need to allot ticket booking from 2017/04/20 to 2017/04/25 .Before inserting this record, I need to check if there is any booking previously happened between the start date 2017/04/20 and end date 2017/04/25

I have tried with below query.But it is not giving the correct result

```
select "id" 
from "table" 
where "from_date" >= '2017-04-20' 
  and "to_date" > '2017-04-20' 
  and "from_date" < '2017-04-25' 
  and "to_date" <= '2017-04-25'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `overlaps` operator:

```
select count(*) = 0 as allow_booking
from "table"
where (from_date, to_date) overlaps (date '2017-04-20', date '2017-04-25');
```

That will also take care of bookings that do not completely fall in the range to test.

The query will return `true` if the booking is allowed, and `false` if not.

Examples:

```
create table bookings 
(
  id serial,
  from_date date, 
  to_date date
);

insert into bookings 
  (from_date, to_date) 
values 
  (date '2017-04-20', date '2017-04-20'),
  (date '2017-04-20', date '2017-04-24'),
  (date '2017-04-26', date '2017-04-29');
```

Then the following

```
select *
from bookings
where (from_date, to_date) overlaps (date '2017-04-18', date '2017-04-19');
```

will return nothing, so, `count(*) = 0` returns `true`

The following query:

```
select *
from bookings
where (from_date, to_date) overlaps (date '2017-04-20', date '2017-04-25');
```

returns:

```
id | from_date  | to_date   
---+------------+-----------
 1 | 2017-04-20 | 2017-04-20
 2 | 2017-04-20 | 2017-04-24
```

So `count(*) = 0` returns `false`

And the query:

```
select *
from bookings
where (from_date, to_date) overlaps (date '2017-04-27', date '2017-04-28');
```

will return:

```
id | from_date  | to_date   
---+------------+-----------
 3 | 2017-04-26 | 2017-04-29
```

And for that `count(*) = 0` is also false.

Comment: But I have to allow booking which are not with in this range.In that case, the query doesn't works

Comment: @user2403954: the query will return those ids that fall into that range. So if the query does not return anything you can allow the booking if not you have to reject it. You could also use a `count(*)` to check that (as you don't really care _which_ bookings exist, only _if_ one exists)

Comment: In my table booking exists from 2017-04-20 only. Now I tried with date range (from_date )2017-04-18  and to_date 2017-04-19. In this case, the expected count as you said is 0,ie., it should allow booking allotment on these dates. But I getting count as 2.

Comment: @user2403954: if you have a booking on `2017-04-20` then the overlaps for `2017-04-18, 2017-04-19` will most certainly **not** return `2`: See an example here: http://rextester.com/TLC97257

Comment: Worked.. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your query does not give the expected result, because you only test for 1 of the 3 (or 4) possible ways of overlapping/intersecting:

```
existing date periods:  +--------------+      +-----+       +----+   +-----+
                            contains        contained by        touches
testing periods:            +------+       +------------+     +---------+
```

To test every possible way of overlapping, you can use [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)'s overlaps operator: `&&`

```
select count(*)
from   booking
where  daterange(from_date, to_date, '[]') && daterange('2017-04-20', '2017-04-25', '[]');
```

But **be warned**: only using these kind of manual checking will not prevent inserting overlapping date ranges in high concurrency. There is a (small) window, after this test & before the actual insertion for another, concurrent statement to insert a conflicting row. To also avoid that, you can use [exclusion constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION):

```
alter table booking
  add constraint exclude_overlapping_bookings
  exclude using gist (daterange(from_date, to_date, '[]') with &&);
```

*Note*: `daterange`'s overlaps operator (`&&`) works the same way as the `overlaps` operator, mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name. Except:

- it supports exclusion constraints
- it supports use of indexes (if you added the exclusion constraint, the index is created automatically for you)
- you can fine-tune how to include the range's boundaries. The default is `[)`, meaning: the lower bound is inclusive, but the upper bound is exclusive. With `overlaps`, this is the **only** supported inclusion.
- `overlaps` works with `timestamp with time zone` values. Your `date` values will be casted to that, using midnight as time & the current `TimeZone` setting. This is may or may not what you want.

http://rextester.com/NNWD52481

Comment: I think `overlaps` can also make use of an index if that contains both date columns

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name as far as I can tell, it cannot. Maybe as index-only scans, but I'm not sure of that either. [It has really one of a kind execution plans.](http://rextester.com/VDGC65027)

Answer (score 1):

Just to examine another way, another query that doesn't use overlap operator, but only AND et OR:
(using data posted by a_horse...).  This is the logic:

**TO_DATE>= [your start date] AND TO_DATE<= [your end date]

OR

FROM_DATE <= [your end date] AND FROM_DATE>= [your start date]**

```
select *
from bookings
where to_date>=date '2017-04-18' AND to_date<=date '2017-04-19'
OR from_date<= date '2017-04-19' AND from_date>=date '2017-04-18';

select *
from bookings
where to_date>=date '2017-04-20' AND to_date<=date '2017-04-25'
OR from_date<= date '2017-04-25' AND from_date>=date '2017-04-20';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. The below query will check if the given start_date or end_date exists in the db.

```
$start_date = '2010-01-01';
$end_date = '2017-01-01';

SELECT * FROM `ticket_history` WHERE 
($start_date <= start_date AND $start_date <= end_date AND 
(($end_date >= start_date AND $end_date >= end_date) OR ($end_date >= 
start_date AND $end_date <= end_date))) OR
($start_date >= start_date AND $start_date <= end_date AND 
(($end_date >= start_date AND $end_date >= end_date) OR ($end_date >= 
start_date AND $end_date <= end_date)))
```